# Permanently available file to download for internet speed testing

Tags: html

I am implementing a very simple download speed tester.
To do that, I simply download a large image file from the web and see if it's received within a reasonable time.

I'm using the following file because I saw that in a source code somewhere:

https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/08/30/01/05/milky-way-2695569_1280.jpg

However, I am afraid that the image might go away some time.

Which image could I use to make sure it will always be there?

Is there perhaps an image that a foundation or so has created especially for such a purpose and who promises that it will be there for a long time?

I was even thinking about downloading a really popular js file because I was thinking that it will be there for a long time like https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js, but I am not sure about this either.

How could I handle this task in the most reliable way?

Thank you!

Comment: You could also host your own image, or you could upload an image to a reliable image hosting service, such as https://imgur.com

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend Wikimedia commons.
Reasons:

1. Wikimedia has a very strict guideline that allows only high quality uploads which of course are higher in size.
2. It's free and persistent (It perisist for years )

You can go with videos for even bigger sizes.
For images it's https://commons.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Images